# Netlogo: "this code can't be run by a patch" when trying to call pcolor?

Tags: netlogo, patch

I'm currently working through the telemarketer IBM in Grimm & Railsback's book. I'm sure it's something really obvious, but I can't figure out why I get the error:

```
this code can't be run by a patch
error while patch -38 75 running IF
  called by procedure MAKE-CALLS
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'step'
```

This is the problematic code (specifically, "if pcolor = black").

```
to make-calls
  ask turtles [
    let territory ( 10 * sqrt size )
    let max-calls floor ( 100 * size )
    let potential-customers patches in-radius territory
    set successful-sales 0
    ifelse count potential-customers <= max-calls
    [
      ask potential-customers[ ;call all customers
        if pcolor = black[
          set pcolor red
          set successful-sales successful-sales + 1
          ]]
      ]  
    [
      ask n-of max-calls potential-customers[ ;call max-calls customers
        if pcolor = black[
          set pcolor red
          set successful-sales successful-sales + 1
          ]]
      ] 
    set total-sales total-sales + successful-sales
  ]
end
```

I want to check whether the patches within the 'territory' of the turtles (the 'potential customers') are coloured black, but the turtles (telemarketers) can only make a certain number of calls. So if the number of patches in their territory exceeds max-calls, I check the colour of a number of patches within the territory equal to max-calls.

Any help would be appreciated :-)

FULL CODE:

```
globals[
  sim-length
  money-size-ratio
  total-sales
  ]

patches-own[
  ;potential customers coloured black, unavailable customers coloured red
  ]

turtles-own[
  ;telemarketers
  funds
  successful-sales
  ]


to setup
  ca
  set sim-length 200
  set money-size-ratio 0.001
  set total-sales 0

  crt initial-num-marketers [
    set size 1.0
    set funds 0.0
    set successful-sales 0
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set shape "circle"
  ]


  ask patches [ set pcolor black ]

end


to go
  reset-phones
  make-calls
  do-accounting
  update-observer
  tick
  if ticks = sim-length [stop]  
end


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;



to reset-phones
  ask patches [ set pcolor black ]
end


to make-calls
  ask turtles [
    let territory ( 10 * sqrt size )
    let max-calls floor ( 100 * size )
    let potential-customers patches in-radius territory
    set successful-sales 0
    ifelse count potential-customers <= max-calls
    [
      ask potential-customers[ ;call all customers
        if pcolor = black[
          set pcolor red
          set successful-sales successful-sales + 1
          ]]
      ]  
    [
      ask n-of max-calls potential-customers[ ;call max-calls customers
        if pcolor = black[
          set pcolor red
          set successful-sales successful-sales + 1
          ]]
      ] 
    set total-sales total-sales + successful-sales
  ]
end


to do-accounting
  ask turtles [
    let costs ( size * 50 )
    let income successful-sales * 2
    set funds funds + income - costs
    if funds > growth-param
    [
      let growth floor ( funds - growth-param )
      set size size + ( size * growth * money-size-ratio )
    ]

    if funds < 0 [ die ]
  ]
end


to update-observer
  set-current-plot "number of businesses"
  plot count turtles

  set-current-plot "business size distribution"
  histogram [size] of turtles

  set-current-plot "total sales"
  plot total-sales

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `successful-sales`: it is a turtle attribute, but you are asking patches to set it.  Change it everywhere to `_sales`, then change `set _sales 0`  to `let _sales 0`.  This introduces a new local variable.  Now your code should work. However, you are no longer using the `successful-sales` attribute of turtles.  Get rid of it.  If you cannot get rid of it for some reason, you can set it to `_sales` right before you update `total-sales`.

Comment: Ah thanks! You're right, I feel so dumb for missing that! I guess I was thrown off because of the error pointing to the if-statement.